# Google Maps is not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-routing

I have created an app that uses Google Maps, the map showed up before I did my routing. But after routing it wont display. Here is my code for the map.
JS:

```
(function() {

  mapController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams'];
  function mapController($scope, $routeParams) {
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.site.Point.coordinates),
        zoom: 5
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    // Save the locationName in the url to the scope
    $scope.locationName = $routeParams.locationName;
  }

  angular.module("siteLookUpApplication").controller("mapController", mapController);
}());
```

HTML:

```
<style>
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100%
  background:#fff;}
</style>
<div>
    <div><a ng-href="#/search">Back To Search</a></div>
    <p>Map for {{locationName}}</p>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a plunk with the full project for additional code: http://plnkr.co/edit/AiVc6nccqke8Jluonpxl?p=preview